# Optimal workload distribution of large scale MPI applications

Tags: optimization, mpi, graph-theory, graph-algorithm, communication

I have a large number of tasks, x, and n MPI ranks (x >> n). Each task has a different workload and requires large communication between a few other tasks.
How do I find an optimal distribution to assign multiple tasks to each rank such that the communication between ranks is minimal and the workload is equal?

In other words:
I have a graph g with x nodes (tasks). Both, the nodes and edges are weighted. I need a graph cluster algorithm which assigns n different colors to each node such that the total weight of all edges between different colors is minimal and each color has (roughly) the same node weights.

Are there algorithms suited for this clustering problem? I thought about simulated annealing or some form of genetic algorithm. Another idea is to cut low weighted edges and to create subgraphs to reduce the problem.

Comment: Is there any dependency between the tasks?  I am thinking that task A might have to wait for task B to complete.

Comment: There is no dependency between the tasks. Metis/Parmetis, Chaco, Zoltan sound like a good approaches.

Answer (score 0):

There are several types of graph algorithms that can be applied. One of the most successful ones is a multi-level partitioning strategy. Read up on the work of Bruce Hendrickson. But this is a lot of coding, and there are libraries already in existence: look up Metis/Parmetis, Chaco, Zoltan.

Comment: I will try it. Thank you!